# Determine if app is running in azure or not

Tags: .net, azure

I have an asp.net mvc app that is built to run as standard web app in iis or in the cloud.

I need to be able to determine if the app is being hosted in azure(dev fabric or cloud) or if it is being run as standard web app under iis.

How can I tell if it is running in cloud?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Think I found it:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable
```

Thanks

@Wheat: Thanks for such a quick response, makes stackoverflow.com a great resource.

Comment: Incidentally RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable only works in a 64-bit environment. Some of our servers are still 32-bit, so I surround it with a try ... catch ... and return false on an exception.

Comment: does Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable work for being able to determine if the asp.net app is running on an Azure VM?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the `StorageAccountInfo` class?:

In your `StorageAccountInfo` object, the property "`usePathStyleUris`" is `false` when you are pointing to cloud storage and `true` when you are pointing to Development Storage locally.