# Determine if webapp code is running in Azure webrole or not

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-roles

What is the best way to determine if my web application code is running in a Azure web role (or emulator)?

I need to configure a dependency injection container and do not want to take a dependency on any Azure specific assemblies unless I'm running in Azure.

Both answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873901/determine-if-app-is-running-in-azure-or-not) require referencing Azure specific assemblies which I'd like to prevent for my on-premise scenario.

**Update**: I'm really looking for something in the runtime environment that I can query from my web application code.

Comment: Add a compilation symbol that will only appear for Azure deployment, then use `#if AZURE` in your dependency configuration.

Comment: I would rather not have to generate separate assemblies for on-premise and Azure.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678419/how-to-check-if-code-is-running-on-azure-websites/25695126#25695126

Comment: @BrendanGreen I want to know if my code is running as a PaaS web role, not an Azure web site. There don't seem to be any Azure specific environment variables set in a web role.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of dependency you're asking about?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Not sure I get your question. I'm trying to configure my authentication OWIN middleware to use WS-Federation for on-premise and OpenID Connect in the cloud. I use Unity with XML configuration for late binding. I want to prevent having to ship Azure specific assemblies to my on-premise deployment.

Comment: What's the rationale behind not wanting a reference to an azure assembly? This feels like it's introducing unnecessary complexity where it isn't needed.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Maybe I'm making this more difficult than needed. It just felt wrong to have to deploy Azure assemblies when running on-prem. Especially since these are used from GAC'd assemblies and thus require to be in the GAC themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - the `CloudConfigurationManager` class in in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration`, which is a nuget package that doesn't need to go into the GAC.  Maybe you are referring to the Service Runtime (which is not needed in this case)?

Comment: I did indeed not realize that the CloudConfigurationManager was in a redistributable assembly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with via a `web.config` / `app.config` / `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` setting that you only set in the specific environments that you want.

Add a parameter, for example:

```
<Setting name="PaaS" value="true" />
```

Then, at application startup, get the value:

```
public bool IsPaaS
{
    get
    {
        var res = false;
        var val = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("PaaS") ?? "false";
        Boolean.TryParse(val, out res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

`CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` will fall back if there is no `cscfg` setting present, and check the `web.config` and/or `app.config`.

Set this in the `WebRole`, but not in the `web.config` when running under local IIS to get the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, this would work, but would also require me to reference Azure specific assemblies to get CloudConfigurationManager. Also, I'd like to determine if I'm running in Azure from the runtime environment, not application configuration.

Comment: How about setting an environment variable as the role starts up?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg432991.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. It did not work. Will try again tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an application setting for your web app through the portal (or ARM template), then check for its value within your code.

[App settings through the Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6viW.png)

```
var isPaaSSetting = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IS_PAAS");
var isPaaS = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(isPaaSSetting) && isPaaSSetting.ToUpper() == "TRUE";
if (isPaaS) {...}
```